# Getting warning from VSCode when using CharAt with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

While trying to pick out the first character of a computed property I used charAt() function on it, but I am getting a little warning from VSCode that it is a wrong usage, although it is working.

computed: {
...mapGetters({
firstname: 'user/firstname',
lastname: 'user/lastname',
}),
initials () {
return (this.firstname.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.lastname.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
}
},

**Property 'charAt' does not exist on type 'Computed'.Vetur(2339)** - This is the warning I get. Could not find much on this over the web

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning caused by `vetur.validation.interpolation` which validate interpolations in region using TypeScript language service.

Setting `vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService: false` in your `settings.json` file will solved this issue for you.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the feedback but I actually don't have 'vetur.validation.interpolation' set up in the project. I am more concerned by the reason for this warning to appear